# How do I find the size of ubuntu 14.04 befor installation?

Tags: 14.04, system-installation

How do I find the size of a fresh ubuntu 14.04 installation with nothing at all added to it before actually installing it? for example I install ubuntu 14.04 and select absolutely nothing and by nothing I mean no desktop environment, software, or anything else excluding the base system that is absolutely required. So how would I find the size of that installation before I install it? I ask this question as I am going to install ubuntu 14.04 on a computer with very limited hard drive space and I would like to be sure that everything will fit on the computer before I go ahead and install it.

I am working with a 6GB hard drive.

Comment: Do you just want a command line interface and no GUI? Or do you want to install the standard Desktop version of Ubuntu? Ubuntu will do a check to see if there is enough space before it starts the install.

Comment: I am looking for a command line interface and I would like to know if the install will leave me with enough space to breath.

Comment: Standard deskstop install takes about 5GB. So 6GB can hold a full desktop install. Once installed, you can uninstall the programs you  don't need. Alternately install the Ubuntu server version. It just needs 1GB. See https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation/SystemRequirements

Comment: Download the Ubuntu Server ISO, boot it on a VM and install using minimal installation mode.

Comment: @Oxwivi I think that might be my best bet as it does not seem like there is any easy way to tell how big the install is until it is done.

Comment: Actually, I just did a minimal installation, but already installed my necessary software before noticing your question, sorry!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The size variation can be very quite a bit because of what files you need for your environment but here are the system requirement for memory if this is helpful.

5 GB of hard-drive space (or USB stick, memory card or external drive but see LiveCD for an alternative approach)

Good luck!

Comment: Will the installation use all 5GB?

Comment: No it should not, but again that depends on what packages you are running and what you are using them for ;)